# Need Help understanding ARM function

Tags: arm

I'm still learning ARM and I couldn't understand what this function is supposed to do.

Can you guys help me out explaining how it works?

```
.text:0006379C           EXPORT _nativeD2AB
.text:0006379C           _nativeD2AB
.text:0006379C           var_28          = -0x28
.text:0006379C
.text:0006379C           STMFD           SP!, {R4-R11,LR}
.text:000637A0           SUB             SP, SP, #0x3A4
.text:000637A4           STMFA           SP, {R0-R3}
.text:000637A8           LDR             R0, =(_GLOBAL_OFFSET_ - 0x637B8)
.text:000637AC           LDR             R1, =(__stack_chk - 0x134EAC)
.text:000637B0           ADD             R0, PC, R0 ; _GLOBAL_OFFSET_
.text:000637B4           LDR             R0, [R1,R0] ; __stack_chk
.text:000637B8           LDR             R0, [R0]
.text:000637BC           STR             R0, [SP,#0x3C8+var_28]
.text:000637C0           MOV             R0, #1
.text:000637C4           ADR             R1, sub_637D0
.text:000637C8           MUL             R0, R1, R0
.text:000637CC           MOV             PC, R0
.text:000637CC           ; End of function _nativeD2AB
```

.

```
.got:00134EAC _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_ DCD 0
```

.

```
.got:00134B0C                 AREA .got, DATA
.got:00134B0C __stack_chk DCD __stack_chkA
```

.

Found the rest of the function. If I understood some of it correctly, it seems to be scrambling the data, though that may be just a wild guess:

```
.text:000637D0 sub_637D0
.text:000637D0                 MOV             R0, #1
.text:000637D4                 ADR             R1, sub_637E0
.text:000637D8                 MUL             R0, R1, R0
.text:000637DC                 MOV             PC, R0
.text:000637DC ; End of function sub_637D0

.text:000637E0 sub_637E0
.text:000637E0
.text:000637E0 arg_14          =  0x14
.text:000637E0
.text:000637E0                 STR             R2, [SP,#arg_14]
.text:000637E4                 MOV             R0, #1
.text:000637E8                 ADR             R1, loc_637F4
.text:000637EC                 MUL             R0, R1, R0
.text:000637F0                 MOV             PC, R0
.text:000637F0 ; End of function sub_637E0

.text:000637F4 loc_637F4
.text:000637F4                 STR             R2, [SP,#0x28]
.text:000637F8                 STR             R0, [SP,#0x18]
.text:000637FC                 MOV             R1, #2
.text:00063800                 STR             R2, [SP,#0x1C]
.text:00063804                 STR             R0, [SP,#0x20]
.text:00063808                 STR             R0, [SP,#0x24]
```

Answer (score 0):

The function has several parts:

1. Store registers to the stacj and reserve space (Strangely, not restored)
2. Load to R0 the address of `GLOBAL_OFFSET` (Once added with PC), to actually access `__stack_chk` (When added to `GLOBAL_OFFSET`). This is done in a very strange way.
3. Load the data at `__stack_chk` and store it in the stack
4. Load to R0 the value of `sub_637D0`, by doing a multiplication by 1. This is the value returned by the function.

So in my opinion, this does not seem to do anything useful...

Comment: "This is the value returned by the function" - it's not returning anything, it's doing a bizarrely computed jump _to_ `sub_637D0`, which is almost certainly a disassembler-generated symbol indicating the very next instruction following the `mov pc, r0` at 0x637cc. Makes me wonder if the `mov r0, #1` is intended to be hotpatched, or it's just the worlds least-optimised single-entry jump table. Either way, we can only wonder what the rest of the function looks like...

Comment: I think i've found the rest of the function. No need to wonder anymore ^^. Btw, thanks for answering.